# What does such notation mean in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
function :: Type1 Type2
```

Are `Type1` and `Type2` return values (tuples)?

```
data Loc = Loc String Int Int 

data Parser b a = P (b -> [(a, b)])

parse :: Parser b a -> b -> [(a, b)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp

type Lexer a = Parser (Loc, String) a

item :: Lexer Char
item = ????
```

How should I return `Lexer` and `Char` from item function? 
Could you please give me some simple example.

Comment: I doubt I can explain this well enough, but at least here's a site that surely can: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Comment: `Lexer` is not a type, `Lexer Char` is a type. It seems that you have skipped ahead a fair bit past the Haskell fundamentals.

Comment: Since you know Java, `Lexer Char` is the Haskell equivalent of Java's `Lexer<Char>`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is *not* a tuple, types can be *parameterized* as well. In imperative languages like Java, this concept is usually know as *generic types* (although there is no one-on-one mapping of the two concepts).

In Java for instance you have classes like:

```
class LinkedList<E> {

    // ...

}
```

Now here we can see `LinkedList` as a function that takes as input a parameter `E`, and then returns a real type (for example `LinkedList<String>` is a linked list that stores `String`s). So we can see such abstract type as a function.

This is a concept that is used in Haskell as well. We have for instance the `Maybe` type:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Notice the `a` here. This is a type parameter that we need to fill in. A function can not return a `Maybe`, it can only return a `Maybe a` where `a` is filled in. For example a `Maybe Char`: a `Maybe` type that is a `Nothing`, or a `Just x` with `x` a `Char`.

Comment: Thans for explanation, it helped me a lot. But i'm still not sure how is should define Lexer from mine example.

Comment: item :: Lexer Char 
item =  Lexer Char (Parser (Loc "f" 1 2) "aaa") 'a'